# Borel subgroup which is a maximal torus is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups

I am struggling with this simple fact. Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of a connected algebraic group $G$. Let $T$ be a maximal torus. Then, if $B = T$, we have $B$ is nilpotent. I don't see why this is true. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: torus is Abelian, so obviously nilpotent.